# How can I connect two tables from different databases using PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql

How can I connect two tables from different databases using PostgreSQL? My first database is called "payments_details" and my second one is called "insurance". Also I want to display and highlight the id's they don't have in common using php, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are isolated from each other, you cannot access data from different databases with one SQL statement. That is not a bug, but a design feature.

There are three ways to achieve what you want:

1. Don't put the data in different databases, but in different schemas in one database. It is a common mistake for people who are more experienced with MySQL to split up data that belong to one application in multiple databases and then try to join them. This is because the term *database* in MySQL is roughly equivalent to what in (standard) SQL is called a *schema*.
2. If you cannot do the above, e.g. because the data really belong to different applications, you can use the [PostgreSQL foreign data wrapper](http://PostgreSQL%20foreign%20data%20wrapper). This enables you to access tables from a different database (or even on a different machine) as if they were local tables. You'll have to write your statements more carefully, because complicated queries can sometimes be inefficient if large amounts of data have to me transferred between the databases.
3. You can use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), which is an older and less comfortable interface than foreign data wrappers, but can allow you to do things that you could not do otherwise, like call a remote function.